# Image from Internet in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible to get a image from a url in kivy?

I want something like this:

```py
src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/373912/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"

img_source = src
```

Comment: There are a bunch of kivy examples out there. How are we better than just picking one of those? If you have an example that isn't doing what you want, that's when we get envolved. But internet search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncImage:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    img = AsyncImage(source="https://images.pexels.com/photos/373912/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260")
    return img

myapp = MyApp()
myapp.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ImageUrl(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ImageUrl = 'http://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png'
        GifUrl = 'https://i.gifer.com/T148.gif'
        self.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=ImageUrl))
        self.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=GifUrl,anim_delay=0.1))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ImageUrl()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

or

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class ImageUrl(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('testApp.kv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

tsetApp.kv

```
ImageUrl:
<ImageUrl>:
    AsyncImage:
        source: 'http://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png'

    AsyncImage:
        source: 'https://i.gifer.com/T148.gif'
        anim_delay: 0.1
```

Document [enter link description here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#asynchronous-loading)

Comment: You are able to see the image on android?